Messages not received from FireBase on Android
I have an app that creates a MulticastMessage intended for both Android and iOS devices and create the message as follows:
var sendMessage = new MulticastMessage()
{
    Data = new Dictionary<string, string>()
    {
        { "eventid", EventId },
    },
    Tokens = idList.ToList(),
    Notification = new Notification()
    {
        Body = message
    },
    Android = new AndroidConfig
    {
        Notification = new AndroidNotification { ClickAction = "TOP_STORY_ACTIVITY", Priority = NotificationPriority.MAX, Sound= "schoolfirealarm.wav" }
    },
    Apns = new ApnsConfig()
    {
        Aps = new Aps()
        {
            CriticalSound = criticalSound
        },
        FcmOptions = new ApnsFcmOptions() { AnalyticsLabel = eventId }
    }
};

var rslt = await FirebaseMessaging.DefaultInstance.SendMulticastAsync(sendMessage);

The cal to SendMulticastAsync returns a result that indicates that all messages were sent and succeeded, however only the iOS devices receive the message. How do I get the Android devices to get the message? Is there something in the structure of the message that is preventing Android from getting them?
